# Change user password in plastic SCM

Tags: passwords, plasticscm

I'm going to work on project, that uses plastic scm for version control. Project manager sent me a message with repo address, my username and generated (at least it looks like randomly generated) password. I'd like to change the password as it seems like a good safety practice to me. I tried to sign in on www.plasticscm.com, as I assumed that manager just created account for me, but I can't log in. Is this possible to change my password, or do I have to ask admin for help?

Answer (score 1):

It's important to clarify if you need to:

1. Change your www.plasticscm.com password: You just need to click on the "Sign in" button and then "I don't have a password / I forgot it". You will receive en email to re-generate the password.
2. If you are using a Plastic hosted server: we have recently released a webadmin tool where you can configure and administer the server, including selecting the authentication mode, creating users and groups (or edit the passwords):
   http://blog.plasticscm.com/2017/10/webadmin-introducing-new-server-admin.html